# How to get User feedback about android app through app

Tags: android

I Developed one Android application(News Aggregate app) . I want to release next version of my application with user feedback option. Through  this option i want to get user feedback/user-response  about my app. But i Don't know how to implement this. Can any one please explain how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't the feedback in Play Store sufficient? You could add a link anywhere in your app pointing to your app in Play Store and ask the user to leave feedback there.

Comment: You can even keep a mailing option in your app, where user can send his feedback to your desired mail id.